# Can personal styles be added to master css file?

Tags: asp.net, css

My question is pretty simple. I have some style classes that I need to use on individual aspx pages. e.g.

```
    .txtbx
    {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     border-style:solid;
     border-width:thin;
     border-color:Gray;
     height:30px;
     width:250px;   
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Now, can I add such styles to the site.css file (that comes as a default when you choose to create a new web application). If yes how do I apply it to the individual .aspx pages since I don't have a head tag there. I read a solution that asks me to include a content place holder in the content (.aspx) page and put the link in it. However I already have two content place holders on each of my content pages. Do I need to add a third one?
Also, would it be better to have another (external) css file to define & use my personal styles such as the one above..? Thnx..!

Answer (score 0):

On your master page :

```
<%@ 
    Master Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="false" 
    CodeBehind="BaseMaster.Master.cs" 
    Inherits="BaseMaster" 
    EnableViewState="false"
%>
<html runat="server" id="htmlTag" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" clientidmode="Static">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphHead" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>

    <body runat="server" id="bodyTag" clientidmode="Static">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphBody" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On your page where you need the style:

```
<%@ 
    Page Title="" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/BaseMaster.Master" 
    AutoEventWireup="false" 
    CodeBehind="..." 
    Inherits="..." 
    EnableViewState="false"
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="server">
    <link runat="server" href="Styles/YOURSTYLE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphBody" runat="server">
    <input type="hidden" id="Field1" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but I can assume following.

1. you have a global .css file, which you want to be applied to all the `.aspx` pages.

   then simply , add a `Link` to the css file in the head section of your `.Master` page
2. you have a local css file, i.e. a css you want to be applied only to a given page, but not to the other pages, in that case, you should do this.

   a. expose the head section of your Master page, by creating a `ContentPlaceHolder` inside the head of the Master Page. i.e (head of Master Page below)

   ```
     <head runat="server">
         <title></title>
         <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="headerContent" runat="server"> 
         </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     </head>
   ```

   b. and use this contentPlaceHolder on your local Page to add link to that local css file.

   ```
    <asp:Content ID="HeadContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="headerContent" 
      runat="server">
      <link runat="server" href="styleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet"      
       type="text/css" />
     </asp:Content>
   ```